# What is the remainder when $3^{57} + 27$ is divided by $28$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Problem: What is the remainder when$$3^{57}+27$$ is divided by $28$ ?

Source: I'm pretty much interested in calculus (you can refer to my previous posts) but I have to prepare for a test where they even put up problems on **elementary number theory.** I got this problem from a practice set and it stumped me. I looked up for similar questions on the website and most of them include the use of $\mathrm{mod}$. **I don't know what it is, and I haven't got time to understand it** as I also have to deal with physics and chemistry at the same time. I have solved a very few problems of this kind (mainly divisibility) using mathematical induction and binomial theorem last year.

My try: When you got integral calculus embedded into your mind, how do you approach without using it? I have tried to develop a function:
$$f(x) = \int(a^x+b)\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int{a^x}\mathrm{d}x + b\int \mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \frac{ a^{x+1}}{x+1} + bx + C$$
put limits $l_l = 0$ and $l_u = 57$ where $l_l$ and $l_u$ are lower and upper limits respectively.

But I have tried to solve it for no good. I can't think of a possible way, and my professor is unwilling to help me with it (duh!). I'm stuck. I have to perform better. So can you please give me an approach without using the **$\mathrm{mod}$ function?** All help appreciated!

Comment: $$3^3\equiv27\equiv-1 (mod28)$$ so $$\quad{3^{57}+27\equiv(3^3)^{19}+27\\\equiv(-1)^{19}+27\\\equiv(-1)+27\\\equiv26 (mod28) \to \\3^{57}+27=28Q+26}$$

Comment: So $3^{57}=(3^3)^{19}\equiv -1 \mod 28$ and $3^{57}+27\equiv 26\mod 28$

Comment: Sirs/madams sir/madam, can you please read the description of the question?

Comment: Your question is analogous to asking for a way to find antiderivatives without integration. Moreover, a vast chunk of elementary number theory revolves around the modulus function.

Comment: Thats true @Raptor, I know that very well, but if one doesn't know it the mod looks just like a modulus I've been dealing thee whole calc course. Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: "So can you please give me an approach without using the mod function?"  No.  I can not and will not.  Why should I. mod function *is* the way to do this and you *are* being tested on knowing the mod function.  And, jeebus, integration of the *continuum* of real numbers to find a *discreet* remainder via divisibility of *integers*.  You must realize that is fruitless.

Comment: no offense @fleablood but if you didn't know about such an approach, there was no need to put it up in the comments. I think that very few high school student are "taught" modular arithmetic, (at least not in my country). And the paper setters are capable enough to know that an average 'highschooler' doesn't know about modular arithmetic, so they encourage us to find a solution from the concepts we know.Take for example a problem on finding the inverse of a matrix using **only** elementary operations then this "No. I can not and will not" won't be any good. Now I hope you get my situation.

Comment: The basics that remainders carry over multiplication and division should be known by must high schools and be the first approach and note $3^3 = 27 = 28 -1$ so $3^{3*19}$ has $(-1)^{19}$ as a remainder should be recognizable even without knowing the technical syntax. However to solve this with calculus is to rebuild an nuclear power generator rather than to change a battery.  Well, to be fair, you probably didn't realize how "fall off the chair" surprising it was to see it suggested.  It's actually jaw dropping.

Comment: @fleablood we've got over with it, I hereby declare myself dumb enough for math if that pleases you. Everybody takes his time to learn, and sometimes even great people fall over on the basics.They also need help. I think the platform is to provide this 'help'. I just don't care what others think about my approach to math, and please don't go overboard when you don't know the dynamics are. Studying calc doesn't imply that I have already 'mastered' all the pre-calc topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want remainder when $3^{57}+27 $ is divided by $28$. Note that $3^{57}=(3^3)^{19}$.

$$3^{57}+27=(3^3)^{19}+27=(28-1)^{19}+27={19\choose0}28^{19}-{19\choose 1}28^{18}\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot+{19\choose18}28-{19\choose19}+27=28k-1+27=28k+26$$

When divided by $28$, $28k+26$ gives $26$ as remainder.

Comment: Thank you, I'm such a noob at number theory that I couldn't even figure this out!

Comment: @YourAverageEuler, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to solve it without the "mod" function.

Note that any polynomial of the form $P(x)=x^{2n+1}+1$ has $x+1$ as a factor, since $P(-1)=(-1)^{2n+1}+1=0$.  In particular,

$$x^{19}+1=(x+1)(x^{18}-x^{17}+x^{16}-\cdots-x+1)$$

Now let $x=3^3=27$.  Then

$$3^{57}+27=(x^{19}+1)+26=(x+1)(x^{18}-x^{17}+\cdots+x^2-x+1)+26\\
=28(3^{18}-3^{17}+\cdots+3^2-3+1)+26$$

so the remainder is $26$.

Remark: What makes this work is that we have $28=3^k+1$ for a power $k$ (namely $k=3$) that divides $57$.

Answer (score 2):

Look.

When you divide $n$ by $d$ you have a remainder of $r$ if $n=q*d + r$.

That would also mean $n = (q+1)*d - (d-r)$.  For all practical purposes, we can talk about a remainder being negative if it makes the math easy.  What difference in the math can it make if we say $n=q*d + r; 0 \le r < d$ or $n = s*d - v; 0 \ge v > -d$?

So the remainder of $27$ divided by $28$ is $-1$.  Let's assume we can say that.

Then $3^3 = 27$ and the remainder of $3^3$ is $-1$.

Now if the remainder of $n$ is $r$ then $n = q*d + r$ for some $q$.  And $a*n = (aq)*d + a*r$.  So if $n$ has $r$ as a remainder, then $a*n$ will have the same remainder as $a*r$.

By induction, $n^m$ will have the same remainder as $r^m$.

So the remainder of $3^{57} + 27= (3^3)^{19} + 27$ will have the same remainder as $(-1)^{19} - 1= -2$.

But we can't actually get away with telling a *professor* that a remainder is negative.  That was just a secret between you and me.  We need a positive remainder.

$-2$ will have the same remainder as $-2 + 28 = 26$.  So the positive remainder is $26$.

Comment: Ha, Thanks @fleablood  this approach is the most suitable to me as its an objective test and I won't have to show my work!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid modular arithmetic, you can use binomial theorem:

Note that $3^{57} = 3^{3 \cdot 19} = 27 ^ {19} = (28-1)^{19}$. Now use the binomial theorem.

$$3^{57 } + 27 = (28-1)^{19} + 28-1 = 28k-2$$

So the remainder is $26$.